# excel Sum every other column up to certain month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Simple spreadsheet with 2 rows:

> ActualJAN | BudgetJAN | ActualFEB | BudgetFEB | ActualMAR | BudgetMAR  ....
>  
>           100             200                        300                     400                      500                      600     ....

I'd like to sum ONLY the Budget columns up to the current month (Month(Today()).
Same for the Actual columns.

So if we're currently in February, 
Budget to date would be: 600=200+400
Actual to date would be: 400=100+300

I just can't seem to get there, at least simply and elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non array formula that performs array like operations.  As such large range references should be avoided or you will experience a slow down or potential crash of your system.  For a small defined range works great so long as the formula is not repeated too many times either.

Additionally TODAY() is a volitile function which means the formula will recalculate whenever anything in the spreadsheet changes, not just when something related to the formula changes.

This formula is generalized a bit so your data can be located anywhere on your sheet and does not require rearrangement of your data.

To get your actual sum use the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$4:$H$4*(COLUMN($C$4:$H$4)-COLUMN($C$4)+1<=MONTH(TODAY())*2)*(LEFT($C$3:$H$3)="A"))
```

To get your Budget sum use the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$4:$H$4*(COLUMN($C$4:$H$4)-COLUMN($C$4)+1<=MONTH(TODAY())*2)*(LEFT($C$3:$H$3)="B"))
```

Change C4:H4 to suit your number range. ChangeC3:H3 to suit your column title range.  Change C4 to be the first cell of your number range.

Caveat:  Assumes maximum 12 months starting at January

Proof of concept:

[image: POC]

Comment: Thank you Forward Ed.  This works brilliantly, but I'm having trouble figuring out why.  Specifically, how does the array in the middle (COLUMN($C$4:$H$4)-COLUMN($C$4)+1<=MONTH(TODAY())*2) "filter" just the months up to and including current month?

Comment: it assumes the months are in chronological order.  so columns 1 and 2 are the first month 3 and 4 the second.  Since you are counting by 2s, you need to multiply today's actual month by 2.  Then its just a matter of making sure your column number is less than or equal to the current month

Comment: The `column(c4)+1` part is just a way to make sure you start counting the columns you are using from 1

Comment: I see how it works now.  I did have to use the "Evaluate Formula" stepping through its execution, to understand how the matrix of {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} creates the appropriate mask by which to multiply and then sum the columns.

Comment: I've read where the Today() function is considered "volatile", in that it recalculates every time a change is made anywhere in the spreadsheet, and can cause stability problems.  I use it in the above formula in about 100 rows.  Am I better off calculating the value of TODAY() a single time, putting the resultant value in a cell and then referencing that cell in my formulas?

Comment: TBH I am not sure. Because each cell reference the one with TODAY in it, they will each in turn be forced to recalc as they are dependent on that cell.  My understanding is that volitle functions in limited usage are ok to use.  To avoid the whole volitle situation, use a reference cell and manually enter the date

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend structuring your data differently. It would be an easier task if you arrayed everything vertically and divided your data into three columns. The first would be **Category**, which would be populated with either "Budget" or "Actual." The next column would be **Month**. After that, of course, you have the **Value** column. Then, use a basic SUMIF, like "=SUMIF(A1:A6,"Budget",C1:C6)." A1:A6 is the range Excel will scan for the desired variable. In this case, that variable is "Budget." Then, C1:C6 is the value that corresponds to a "Budget" month. That formula will give you the answer you want as long as you expand the SUMIF formula to include the full range of values, e.g., "SUMIF(A1:A317,"Budget",C1:C317)."

Comment: Where on the spreadsheet do you want the budget to dates? Does your data go for the rest of the year?

Comment: @Ziggus Not sure if that's meant for me, but it does seem important to know if there is more specific date information in this situation.

Comment: Tigelle and @Ziggus I believe it was a comment meant for the general question.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I understand what you're trying to do, I cannot make the entire formula without the rest of the spreadsheet but this is working currently:

For the Actual:

```
=IF(MONTH(TODAY())=1,A2,IF(MONTH(TODAY())=2,A2+C2,IF(MONTH(TODAY())=3,A2+C2+E2,"")))
```

For the Budget:

```
=IF(MONTH(TODAY())=1,B2,IF(MONTH(TODAY())=2,B2+D2,IF(MONTH(TODAY())=3,B2+D2+F2,"")))
```

Here is the spreadsheet I created to test:

[image: Sample spreadsheet]

If you give me the rest of the data I can complete the formula, basically all you would need to do is add more months to the formula and change the amounts it adds.

I am sure there is probably a more efficient way to accomplish this but this way works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a hidden row to control your dates. Say, January is in column C, enter [C1] =1, [D1] =C1, [E1] =C1+1, [F1] =E1. Select E1:F1 and copy to the right until December. Hide row 1.

In row 2 use these two formulas.

`[C2] ="Actual" & UPPER(TEXT("1/" & C$1,"mmm"))`

`[D2] ="Budget" & UPPER(TEXT("1/" & D$1,"mmm"))`

Select C2:D2 and copy to the right until December. This exercise isn't required because the resulting display is exactly what you already have. But producing this result with the help of formulas ensures freedom from error, and it is faster. As an added bonus you get a visual check of what's in the hidden row.

Now you can use this formula to extract totals from row 3 where you have your values.

`=SUMIFS($C3:$Z3,$C$2:$Z$2,"Budget*",$C$1:$Z$1,"<="&MONTH(TODAY()))`

Change "Budget" to "Actual" and the same formula will extract the actual amounts.